# Merge and give condensed times javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to solve interview cake problem.

> Basically, I need to Write a function mergeRanges() that takes an
>   array of meeting time ranges and returns an array of condensed ranges.

Example:

```
[
    {startTime: 0,  endTime: 1},
    {startTime: 3,  endTime: 5},
    {startTime: 4,  endTime: 8},
    {startTime: 10, endTime: 12},
    {startTime: 9,  endTime: 10},
]
```

Expected Output:

```
[
    {startTime: 0, endTime: 1},
    {startTime: 3, endTime: 8},
    {startTime: 9, endTime: 12},
]
```

**My attempt:**

```
var input = [
    {startTime: 0,  endTime: 1},
    {startTime: 3,  endTime: 5},
    {startTime: 4,  endTime: 8},
    {startTime: 10, endTime: 12},
    {startTime: 9,  endTime: 10},
]

function mergeRanges(input){

  function compare(a,b){
    if(a.startTime < b.startTime){ return -1; }
    if(a.startTime > b.startTime){ return 1;  }
    return 0;
  }

  var a= input.sort(compare); //sort the input JSON array.

  return input.reduce(function(acc, val, index){
    if(index != 0){ //if not the first index, compare current to previous object

      if(val.startTime < acc.endTime || val.endTime > acc.endTime){
        acc[startTime] = acc.startTime;
        acc[endTime] = val.endTime;
      } else {
        acc[startTime] = val.startTime;
        acc[endTime] = val.endTime;
      }


    } else { //if i==0 then just let the object pass
      acc = val; 
    }

    return acc;
  }, {});
}

mergeRanges(input);
```

But it seems like i'm getting startTime is not defined. Can someone help me to solve this mystery?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have an object as accumulator, then the accumulator is empty and any attempt to access the accumulator gets `undefined`.

You could sort the array by `start` and `end` and iterate the sorted array with a check for the ranges if they overlap.

```js
var data = [{ startTime: 0,  endTime: 1 }, { startTime: 3,  endTime: 5 }, { startTime: 4,  endTime: 8 }, { startTime: 10, endTime: 12 }, { startTime: 9,  endTime: 10 }],
    result = data
        .sort(function (a, b) { return a.startTime - b.startTime || a.endTime - b.endTime; })
        .reduce(function (r, a) {
            var last = r[r.length - 1] || {};
            if (a.startTime <= last.endTime) {
                if (last.endTime < a.endTime) {
                    last.endTime = a.endTime;
                }
                return r;
            }
            return r.concat(a);
        }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you @Nina Scholz can you explain me why you are returning 'r' and why are you concatenating it with 'a'? kinda confused here. Can you explain the algorithm in general. I got the essence of it but I want to understand it completely.

Comment: `r` is the accumulator array, which is at start empty. it gets filled with the items of `data` which are denoted by `a`. inside of [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), the last element of the accmulator is taken or an empty object for the checks. then a new endTime is assigned or the element `a` is pushed to the accumulator `r`.